# How to handle the Time data from the Style just like "Wed Jun 20 11:01:05 +0800 2012"?

Tags: java, json, time

In my project ,I get json data from Server,there's a field named 'creat_at' in the json which style is like 'Wed Jun 20 11:01:05 +0800 2012'

How to change it to more easy-to-read style like '2012/06/20'?

(I have tried 'DateFormat.parse' but it dose not work:
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy").parse(dateString) 
cause
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Jun 20 11:00:53 +0800 2012")

Comment: Well if you can format it in the server end just use DateFormatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
System.out.println(sdf2.format(sdf.parse("Wed Jun 20 11:01:05 +0800 2012")));
```

prints

```
2012/06/20
```

You may also need to set an approriate timezone.

Comment: Thank you ,I tried your code but it throws java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Jun 20 11:01:05 +0800 2012"

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? Older versions of Java fail to handle timezones with `+0800` Try taking this out and the "Z" in the format.

Comment: I have tried Sun/Oracle HotSpot Java 7 update 5, Java 6 update 33, and Java 5 update 22 and they all parse this string correctly.

Answer (score 2):

See [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) API

```
Date date  = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy").parse(dateString);
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(date);
```

Comment: Thank you but it throws a exception:java.text.ParseException

Comment: What was given as `dateString` ?

Comment: it's 'Wed Jun 20 11:01:05 +0800 2012'